# Adding the inreg attribute to LLVM IR function parameters

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm working with LLVM and I want to recreate a piece of IR with the API:

```
declare void @fun(i32* inreg, i32 inreg)
```

But I can't seem to get it to actually do it.

My current attempt is:

```
Function* fun = cast<Function>(M.getOrInsertFunction("fun",type));

((fun -> getAttributes()).getParamAttributes(0)).addAttribute(c,0,Attribute::InReg);

((fun -> getAttributes()).getParamAttributes(1)).addAttribute(c,0,Attribute::InReg);
```

This code literally doesn't do anything after line 1, lines 2 and 3 are completely ignored and all I get in the IR output is:

```
declare void @fun(i32* , i32 )
```

How do I get it to work correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Managing function attributes in LLVM is quite inconvenient as attributes are packed into immutable and global sets. Assigning an attribute to a function argument actually means replacing the set representing all function and argument attributes with a new one.

Fortunately, there are at least helper functions that makes that job a bit easier. I suggest using [`llvm::Function::addAttribute()`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Function.html#a9c49c5271c8223918bcac7b116e935c4) method.

```cpp
Function* fun = cast<Function>(M.getOrInsertFunction("fun", type));
fun->addAttribute(1, Attribute::InReg);
fun->addAttribute(2, Attribute::InReg);
```

Keep in mind that index 0 represents *function* attributes, *argument* attributes starts from index 1.

Comment: This comment was useful but one key part is wrong:
Function attributes have index `-1 = ~0` (at least in the latest LLVM).
This can be seen in `llvm::AttributeList::AttrIndex::FunctionIndex`.
Index `0` is reserved for return value attributes.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems with your code snippet.

First, the index of the first parameter is 1, not 0. So you should be using indices 1 and 2, not 0 and 1.

Second, `addAttribute()` does not modify its receiver, it instead returns a new set. So the proper way to change attributes would be to do:

```
fun->setAttributes(fun->getAttributes().addAttribute(1, ...));
```

And finally, there's a shorthand for the above, which is just to do:

```
fun->addAttribute(1, ...);
```